# CS0012 error when building Origami (Hololens 101 tutorial)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, hololens

I have been tortured by the CS0012 error for one week ([reported problem](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/10512/cs0012-error-when-trying-to-deploy-origami-hololens-101-tutorial-to-hololens#latest))

Briefly speaking, I follow the [Holograms 101 tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-101). When I tried to deploy the holograms to Hololens at the end of Chapter 1, I encountered two errors and the build failed. Two errors are:

`The type "CoreApplicationView" is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly "Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime".`

`The type "CoreWindow" is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly "Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime".`

I have searched online for solutions but I turned out to find some same questions without a valid solution, or solutions which didn't work for me.

I'm using win10 OS, Visual Sudio Community 2017 Version 15.7.1, Unity 2017.2.0f3.

I was wondering whether the errors have something to do with `Assembly-CSharp-firstpass`. After generating the APP, under the dir Origami/App/GeneratedProjects/UWP there is only one folder Assembly-CSharp but no Assembly-CSharp-firstpass. I also tried to search anything related to Assembly-CSharp-firstpass under the Origami dir but there's nothing. However, I never encountered the error "Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll is not found" which some people reported.

Anybody has experience with this problem? Thanks a lot in advance for any help!!

Comment: I would double check the build settings in Unity: Target platform: UWP (check that the unity logo is next to it and if it’s not, click on UWP and click on “switch platform” below, then wait for the unity logo to move beside UWP), check target device (Any Device or HoloLens). Also PlayerSettings, in the XR Settings section, check VIrtual Reality Supported, and see that there is something like “Windows Holographic” or “Windows Mixed Reality” there. Finally, look at the scripting backend and see if it gives you any errors or warnings. Good luck

Comment: @Leon thank you for your comments. What do you mean by "scripting backend"? All the others are all correct from my side. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome. The scripting backend is a setting from Player Settings. I think it is in the “Other settings” section. Sometimes you can have a setting chosen there for which you don’t have certain requisites installed. In that case you would normally see a warning in the Build Settings window.  Here’s some info on the scripting backend (not a lot though): https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-scriptingbackends.html

Comment: I see, my scripting backend is indeed .NET which I think is correct....

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, let me answer my own question. I have figured it out.

If you also use win10, VS2017, and unity 2017 (I'm using 2017.2, but I guess this should also work for 2017.3/4), then in the case of these two annoying "assembly that is not referenced" problem, check whether you have a reference called "windows" under Origami assembly->References. If it is not there, then right click References, on the left side you will see a "Browse", under the Browse, browse to add the reference which is supposed to be at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Facade\windows.winmd

I hope this helps you guys. Good luck!